# Error Connecting to SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm programmatically attempting to connect to SPO but receiving this error:

> Identity Client Runtime Library (IDCRL) could not look up the realm
>   information for a federated sign-in.

It just started happening this morning with code that has been working for months. Could there have been something changed at the Tenant level?

```
ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

It will throw an exception on the above line randomly. Almost every second or third time. Any ideas?

Comment: I guess this doesn't give any leads? https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29438.connect-sposervice-identity-client-runtime-library-idcrl-could-not-look-up-the-realm-information-for-a-federated-sign-in.aspx

Comment: Nah unfortunately, it's not bad credentials that is the issue. It looks like OfficeDevPnP has been updated. All of my projects that reference it are broken today